# pure css solution to add some text

Tags: html, css, text, tags

I'm trying to add text in this structure with pure css:

```
<div><i></i>world!</div>
```

so it would look like

```
<div><i></i>Hello, world!</div>
```

on the page.
The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RbLRA/) example contains this css style:

```
div{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;

}
i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url("http://png-.findicons.com/files/icons/1688/web_blog/48/pencil_small.png");
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

My bad solution is to add:

```
i:after {
content: "Hello, ";
}
```

but it doesn't put the text "Hello, " where I actually want and the style from `i` applied.
So, is there any way to add `Hello,` right in front of another text with the same style?

**Please only css solution.**
Thank you.

P.S. And here is  [my bad solution @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RbLRA/1/)

It should be like this:
[image]

Comment: why do you want to add with CSS in the first place ?

Comment: CSS was invented to style the document. Not to edit the document. huh!

Comment: Adding content with CSS isn't accessible by screen readers.

Comment: That's not my project and such customization is needed. CSS is the best way in my case (if solution exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/RbLRA/2/

Is this how you want it? Your first fiddle doesn't help a lot - is the text meant to overlap the pencil image?
Anyway, you can style the pseudo-element itself to have the green border, and remove the browser default styling from the  tags which is usually italic, using:

```
font-style: normal;
```

It's not considered semantic to use the  tag either in this case, just a thought...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I've added the image as it has to look. Sorry, I has to add it when I opened the question. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this, to be honest - why aren't you just typing 'Hello' before 'World' in the HTML? Also, you have an <i> which only has a background image in it. If you want the 'Hello' part to be dynamic, you'll have to use Javascript anyway, and then you're much better off inserting the extra word with JS as well.

Comment: That's because the customization of css is easier in my case.